# NodeJS multiple URLs on same server

Tags: node.js

I want to host multiple NodeJS apps on 1 server. I give different port numbers to every app, so I can go to every app with http://example.com:8080, http://example.com:4567 etc. However, now I want to assign different URLs to these different apps, but I can't assign URL to port number. So, how can i do it? I don't want to for example, have a base app to check URL with switch/case and then just redirect to some port, I need it to behave like completely different apps. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run them all on the same Node.js process, but [mount](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) each app in a separate path.

You can change each script to export a function that takes an Express app and a mount path, then pass that path to each piece of middleware it installs.