# How to create multiple socket server instance on the same server

Tags: node.js, server

I would like to know if it's possible to create multiple socket servers on differents url routes on only one nodejs server.

I'm trying to have two differents server instance running on differents url
like mysite/instanceA and mysite/instanceB

When i tried to do that with port and not url. The application start well and on the port 3000 and 3001, i got two distincts application. It's great.

```
let express = require('express');
let http = require('http');
let socket = require('socket.io');
let workspace = require('./src/workspace');

class Server {
    constructor(port){
        this.httpServer = http.Server(app);
        this.io = socket(this.httpServer);
        workspace.newWorkspace(this.io , app);
        this.httpServer.listen(port, function(){
            console.log('App started on : ' + port);
        });
    }
}

let app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
new Server(3000);
new Server(3001);
```

But, i want do that with url and not port, so i tried something like that. I know why is not worked but i didn't know how to realize my aim.

Example:

```
let express = require('express');
let http = require('http');
let socket = require('socket.io');
let workspace = require('./src/workspace');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;

class Server {
    constructor(){
        this.httpServer = http.Server(app);
        this.io = socket(this.httpServer);
        workspace.newWorkspace(this.io , app);
        this.httpServer.listen(port, function(){
            console.log('App started on : ' + port);
        });
    }
}

let app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    new Server();
});
app.get("/a", function(req, res){
    new Server();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS multiple URLs on same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749698/nodejs-multiple-urls-on-same-server)

Comment: Nop :s sorry it's not that but thank's to reply :)